# VPN and internet access on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ssh, vpn

My aim is to connect through a VPN via L2TP to my 4G router at home to exploit an SSH connection. I have linux KDE installed. The connection is established correctly but most of the most heavy websites (stackoverflow itself) will not work (instead wikipedia is working). The SSH connection is established via terminal but it is not working on VS Code.

What I tried to now:

```
reduce the MTU on 4G router and also change the router.
connecting to the same router via MacOs is working fine.
connecting to another router (completely different internet provider/connection) works.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What sort of error do you receive? Edit your question instead of submitting a temporary comment